# VueJS: Adding custom schema validation to Monaco Editor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, monaco-editor

I'm using vuejs with typescript to create a component based off of [Monaco Editor json validation](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults) , so far it's working fine and rendering correctly but i've a small issue where i'm unable to provide custom schema validation to the monaco editor, As of now this is my implementation but when i pass down the schema as a prop to monaco editor child.tsx file, it does'nt work, Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Parent.tsx file where i'm using the Monaco editor** and defined the prop

```
data() {
        const id = 'foo.json';
        const validCardSchema = [{
            uri: 'http://myserver/foo-schema.json',
            fileMatch: [id],
            schema: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    p1: {
                        enum: ['v1', 'v2']
                    },
                    p2: {
                        $ref: 'http://myserver/bar-schema.json'
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            uri: 'http://myserver/bar-schema.json',
            fileMatch: [id],
            schema: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    q1: {
                        enum: ['x1', 'x2']
                    }
                }
            }
        }];

        return {
            jsonEditorText: JSON.stringify(editorCode),
            validCardSchema
        };
}

<TMonacoEditor
    width="400"
    height="400"
    language="json"
    style="border: none;"
    code={this.MonacoEditorText}
    onCodeChange={newVal => this.updateMonacoEditorText(newVal)} />
```

And the file

child.tsx file where monaco editor functionality is defined

```
createMonaco() {
            debugger;

            this.editor = monaco.editor.create(this.$el, this.editorOptions);
            this.editor.onDidChangeModelContent(event =>
                this.$emit('codeChange', this.editor.getValue())
            );

            console.log(this.cardSchema);
            monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
                validate: true,
                schemas: this.cardSchema
            });

            this.monaco = monaco;

        }
    },
    render(h): VNode {
        return <div style={this.style} />;
    }
```

So, this condition above does'nt show any validation error even if i pass the wrong json properties which are not defined in the props schema.

monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
                    validate: true,
                    schemas: this.cardSchema
                });

Comment: To make this question more easy to answer, add context as to whats not working. What do you mean by 'it doesnt work'?

Comment: i just updated at the end of my post, but just an fyi,

So, this condition in createdMonaco does'nt show any validation warning even if i pass the wrong json properties which are not defined in the props schema.

             
   monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
                    validate: true,
                    schemas: this.cardSchema
   });